# Is it possible to run DataStax OpsCenter on Windows?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

**Context**

I am just "installed" Cassandra 3.11.11 on a Windows 2019 Server ("installed" means unpacked the tar, set all environment, and run). Did some smoke tests all with success cqlsh and nodetool all seems to be OK.

**What I've tried so far**

Now I would like to install DataStax OpsCenter, but in the [DataStax download site](https://downloads.datastax.com/#enterprise-ops-center) I could not find Windows version. I thought it worth a try, having all JVM and Python prerequisites in place, because of the already running C*, I downloaded the tarball, unpacked, but obviously opcenter file which is a bash shell will not run, also both setup.py and start_opscenter.py gives error.

> setup.py: File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in
> _execute_child
> startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

> start_opscenter: File
> "C:\cassandra\opscenter-6.8.15\bin\start_opscenter.py", line 1, in
>
> from opscenterd import opscenterd_tap ImportError: No module named opscenterd

**Question**

Is there any way to run DataStax OpsCenter in Windows Server, I should I give up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Alex's answer, OpsCenter is not designed to run on Windows.

It is only supported to run on some Linux distributions mainly Ubuntu, CentOS/RHEL and associated flavours.

There is no "community edition" or other variants of OpsCenter apart from the enterprise version which only works with DataStax Enterprise.

As a side note, there is very limited Windows support in Cassandra 3.11 and there are several known issues that will not be fixed due to limitations in the operating system.

Furthermore, Windows support has been completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 due to lack of maintainers and testing ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

As a workaround, we recommend the following:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-docker-image)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

If you just want to build apps with Cassandra as a backend, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier that lets you launch a Cassandra cluster in a few clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

DataStax OpsCenter works only with DataStax Enterprise, and couldn't be used with Apache Cassandra.  From the description on download site:

> OpsCenter is an easy-to-use visual management and monitoring solution for **DataStax Enterprise (DSE)**.

Comment: Many thanks, but the question was about if it is possible to run on Windows. There is a OpsCenter Community Edition, what I did not find btw

Comment: Community edition of OpsCenter is discontinued long time ago, and it was working with specific versions of Cassandra (quite old)

Comment: Thx for clarification